# Nolinear system of equations.

Tags: transcendental-equations

$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
x^y = y^x \\
 x-y\cdot\log_xy=(x+y)\cdot\log_xy
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You got one answer and now you are already expecting another. Without even trying.

Comment: @MFG Flay: I edtied your question. please feel free to edit it to your liking.

Comment: Dear, UrosSlovenija. Not true, this exercies I've been trying to resolve for a while . Just today i've found about this forum, and that's the reason I'm posting the problemes. I guarantee you that this exercises gave me some headache ttrying to solve them.

Comment: But you can still give us some thoughts. If you tried hard then you should have some insight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With rules for logarithms the second equation translates to 
$$
x - y\log_xy = \log_x y^x + y \log_x y
$$
and using the first equation this simplifies to
$$
x= y+2y (1+\log_xy)
$$
and then 
$$
\log_xy = \frac{x-y}{2y}
$$
From first equation you can express
$$
y = x^{\frac{y}{x}}
$$
implying 
$$
\frac{y}{x} = \frac{x-y}{2y}
$$
which translates to 
$$
x^2 -xy - 2y^2 = 0
$$
and factoring this you get
$$
(x+y)(x-2y)=0
$$
that gives $2$ solutions which, as usual with equation with logarithms, need to be checked. Try.

Comment: Thank you... And, of course, x,y can't be 1 , and x,y > 0. Right?

Comment: I've corrected the question, someone else edit it wrong

Comment: @MFGFlay Are you sure the equations are now correct? And where are you getting these problems? Homework or something else?

Comment: UrosSlovenija, yes it is correct. While I was watching your demonstration I saw that something isn't wrong, because I tried to solve it many times but no success for me ... Then I checked the equation system and It was wrong, Now it is correct. Yep , it is homework

Comment: @MFGFlay i edited. check and get back to me

Comment: Well, the first case: x=-y, is impossible, because x,y > 0. The 2nd case: x=2y => I obtained : y=2, x=4. I guess these are the solutions, thanks !

Comment: Sorry, I checked it. I'm newbie on this forum discussion ... Thanks again!